# What's the opposite of a zero inflation model?

Tags: zero-inflation, capture-mark-recapture

I have an ecological dataset of capture-recapture encounters. I don't have any 0 occurrences because if an animal was not encountered, it was not noted in the dataset. Thus, my dataset doesn't have *enough* zeros. How can I add zeros for "no encounter"s using a probability of having a 0 value along with the mean of counts (my data fits a Pareto distribution)?

In other words, is there a model that does the opposite of a zero-inflated model and instead *adds* more 0s to a dataset?

Comment: You probably need to tell us more on what exactly is your data and why "not enough zeros" is a problem?

Comment: @Tim i am using the capture-recapture data to assess animal movements between occurrences, but a non-occurrence between these occurrences would not mean that they are no longer there, just that they were not active (remained burrowed, for example) during that surveying event. Thus, I want more 0s for those times they were inactive. I was thinking of using a probability of detection to do that, but I wanted to see if something exists out there

Comment: So you re-captured all the animals? This seems like legit result, unless I’m misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Tim we can only re-capture the individual animal when it is active, but for a study on movements I would like to emphasize that sometimes they don't move at all (stay inactive). As all data on movements are based on active animals, it looks like animals are always on the move. I have too many individuals and sampling events to simply add 0s for each event based on each individual's presence/absence (it would add too many 0s!), that's why I was looking into something similar to a zero-inflation model, but that adds 0s instead.

Comment: In other words, I want my movement distances kernel to also have values for 0s for a more realistic distribution

Comment: But the initially captured animals were on move as well? If so, in both cases you sample from same population of animals in the move, don’t you?

Comment: Animals captured on the move are not always on the move - they might be on the move in surveying event 1 and then not in the next. Animals are not either always active or either always inactive